# What does this error means on my membership Contribution page?

Tags: civimember, error, contribution-page

Whenever my membership contribution page is loaded, I am getting this notice in drupal log. What does it mean? It’s not that I have an issue processing payment On this page, but just curious! Thanks in advance.

```
Notice: Undefined index: minimum_fee in CRM_Member_BAO_MembershipType::getAllMembershipTypes() (line 844 of /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/MembershipType.php).
```

Comment: If you go to `Administer > CiviMember > Membership Types`, do all your types have a 'minimum fee' entered?

Comment: Thanks @Aidan, filling in "minimum fee" solved the problem.

Comment: Good. The code is assuming a minimum fee is set, but the field is not marked as required.  The help text on the membership type setup says to use 0 for free memberships so I'm not clear what the use case is for no minimum fee. Either the code should not assume it is set, or the field should be mandatory.  Let's see who else chimes in here.